# Get TextBox value from div. Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am creating a dojo TextBox inside a div and then the div is stored in an array.
Now I want to get the value of TextBox from the array.

```
var div = domConstruct.create("div",null,"someContainer","last");<br />
var textBox = new TextBox({
        name : "SomeName"
}, div);
this.inputs["Property1"]["Property2"] = div;
```

Given property1 and 2, I want to use the inputs array to get value of the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your TextBox an id you can simply access it by an ID
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/byId.html

```
var textBox = new TextBox({
        name : "SomeName",
        id: "uniqueId",
}, div);
```

Comment: That will work...But actually I am creating a lot of textBoxes inside a loop. So, I did not want to use the id.

Answer (score 0):

To get value for above code your can try this :

```
this.inputs["Property1"]["Property2"].value;
```

or

```
this.inputs["Property1"]["Property2"].get("value");
```

Comment: Tried this.inputs["Property1"]["Property2"].value didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem,
By storing the textBox in the array instead of the div.
this.inputs["Property1"]["Property2"].value will then give the value.

Still not sure how to work with div.